# Xcode Clang error file not found

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, clang

Wondering if I can get some direction here; I've got 18 Warnings (which I think are all deprecated functions for SDK(s) for in-ap-advertising. I'm working through them separately. The only error I have is as follows, causing me to be unable to run on both iOS Simulators and on physical devices.

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '_ObjC'
```

The masses of text immediately above this give file paths for what looks like all the compile source paths.

I can confirm that the Build Settings - Linking-Other Linker Flags contains "-all_load" and "_ObjC".

I've had a look about and have found similar questions and tried to transpose the answers into something that will relate to my Error, but am going a bit mad right now because it's probably something really simple :|

Please let me know if you require any further information or screenshots etc., etc.

Regards,

I'm Mad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should be `-ObjC`, a hyphen, not `_ObjC`, an underscore.

Comment: ah, that's worked a treat, brilliant! Thanks. I had to remove and re-add some libraries but I think it was just Xcode doing it's thing. Thanks again!